# In Django, how can one find all other active sessions of the currently logged in user?

Tags: django-sessions

I want to notify a user about her being also logged in from other computer(s), with an option to close these other sessions. Unfortunately it'd not immediately obvious how to do it in Django without hacking the database directly.

Answer (score 0):

You can store multiple token in visitor cookie and validate them against a list of token in the db. If they are multiple token in the db user profile you will be sure that the user is logged in from different browser. Flusing every token will disconnect the user from other computers.

Answer (score 0):

you can find the logged in users session by checking the session is expired or not. you can catch the logged in users session by

```
Session.objects.filter(expire_date__gte=timezone.now())
```